# Scala:hierarchy relationship

Tags: scala

[Here](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/), following is explained

```
trait A { def common = “A” }
trait B extends A { override def common = “B” }
trait C extends A { override def common = “C” }
class D1 extends B with C
class D2 extends C with B
```

In case of (D1), the superclass of C is B.

Following same reasoning, in case of (D2), the superclass of B is C.

So is it possible to vary hierarchy relationships dynamically by varying traits linearly?

Also asked here:
https://users.scala-lang.org/t/type-linearization/2533

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for something like `val d1 = new B with C` and `val d2 = new C with B`?

Comment: What I mean is in case of (D1),the superclass of C is B. Similarly in case of (D2), the superclass of B is C.. So in same program, we have different class relationship between B and C. We don't have such thing in Java.But in Scala it seems to be possible.This is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit big for a comment, so:

In both cases (`D1` and `D2`) `B` extends `A` and `C` also extends `A`. `B` and `C` don't become superclasses of each other, it's just the matter of how Scala resolves the diamond problem.

Think of type linearization as of "if you mix in 2 traits that extend from a common parent and thus implement a method with the same signature, the rightmost one wins". This means that in your examples:

```
class D1 extends B with C
```

`B` and `C` both implement `A`, but `C` is the rightmost in `D1` definition. This means `C.common` will be called if you call `common` on `D1`. And in the next example:

```
class D2 extends C with B
```

the story is just the same, but `B` is the rightmost in its definition, thus its implementation will be called on `D2.common`